# Ionic 5 pass value from Modal to Page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I need to pass a data (just one string) from a modal to his "parent page" on Ionic5, basically when the user click on an item of the Modal it should pass the string to the page which filter in an array and show the result

Those are the clickable items on the modal:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col class="ion-no-padding-vertical">
    <ion-list class="ion-no-padding-vertical">
        <ion-item class="ion-no-border" button>
          <ion-icon class="ion-input-icon-big" slot="start" name="bu"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Burn</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>

<ion-row>
  <ion-col class="ion-no-padding-vertical">
    <ion-list class="ion-no-padding-vertical">
        <ion-item class="ion-no-border" button>
          <ion-icon class="ion-input-icon-big" slot="start" name="be-battery-weak"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Battery Too Weak</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

This is the page.ts of the modal:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cmd-v4-modal',
  templateUrl: './cmd-v4-modal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cmd-v4-modal.page.scss'],
})
export class CmdV4ModalPage implements OnInit {
 constructor(private modalController: ModalController) { }
 ngOnInit() { }
 async closeModal() {
     await this.modalController.dismiss();
 }
}
```

and this is the page.ts of the "parent" page:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

import { CmdV4ModalPage } from './cmd-v4-modal/cmd-v4-modal.page';
import * as cmd_v4_error_json from '../../assets/ErrorCodes/CMD-V4-ERROR.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cmd-v4',
  templateUrl: './cmd-v4.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cmd-v4.page.scss'],
})
export class CmdV4Page implements OnInit {

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) { }

  async CMDV4Modal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: CmdV4ModalPage
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

I tried to Google but I don't find a way to achieve this.
Thanks

> REPLY to Peter

thank you so much for the help but I just have an error:

error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

got this on modal.page.ts

```
async closeModal() {
let data = { name : 'John'};
this.modalController.dismiss(data);
}
```

and this on the main page cmd-v4.ts (parent page)

```
async CMDV4Modal() {
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
component: CmdV4ModalPage
});
modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
console.log(data);
});
return await modal.present();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the `dismiss()` method pass the string:

```
let data = { name : 'John'};
this.modalController.dismiss(data);
```

Then in your page, you can use `onDidDismiss()` to get the value from the modal:

```
  async CMDV4Modal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: CmdV4ModalPage
    });
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
     console.log(data);
   });
   await modal.present();
  }
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help but I just have an error:

error TS2554: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.


got this on modal.page.ts

async closeModal() {
   let data = { name : 'John'};
   this.modalController.dismiss(data);
}

and this on the main page cmd-v4.ts (parent page)

  async CMDV4Modal() {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: CmdV4ModalPage
    });
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
     console.log(data);
   });
   return await modal.present();
  }

Comment: It doesn't format the code :/... I'll add my last post to the main one

Comment: In the modal page instead of modalController use View Controller class in the constructor

Comment: I have been trying to resolve this with event emitter and I tried so many different ways and failed, thank you for this straightforward answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
async CMDV4Modal() {
  const modal = await this.modalController.create({
    component: CmdV4ModalPage
  });
  modal.onDidDismiss()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
  });
 await modal.present();
}
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you were to [edit] it and add an explanation of how this code solves the question